# detect and redirect based on URL

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

I have the following conditions in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex\.co$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?ref=$1 [L,R]
```

This will forward `ex.co\xxxxxx` to `example.com\?ref=xxxxxx`.

What I want is to add a line that if a user simply goes to `ex.co` it redirects to `example.com` and not (as it does currently) `example.com?ref=`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add the third line below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex\.co$
RewriteRule ^$     http://example.com [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?ref=$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hm... maybe `^$` instead of `^/$`?

Comment: Yep that worked! Thanks, I can't change your answer though, so you will have to...Then I'll accept.

Comment: :) Done... I always get confused about whether the URL is empty or / when the request is to the domain root :|